# Closed an open recursion symbol understanding

Tags: recursion, programming-languages, computer-science, notation

This question is not directly about what is open or closed recursion as we could see on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803621/why-is-it-called-open-or-closed-recursion) question, but it's more specifically about [this talk](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ralf.hinze/talks/Open.pdf) which is referenced in many placed.

Inside we can see expression such as:

```
(fun(x1:τ1)⇒e)⇓(fun(x1:τ1)⇒e)
```

My question is: what does the `⇓` stand for?

I looked around this internet and didn't found anything particular about that, taking into account that googling a symbol is always tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it does answer your question, but from reading various material online I think `⇓` means **evaluates to** or **reduced to**.

For expression:

```
(fun(x1:τ1)⇒e)⇓(fun(x1:τ1)⇒e)
```

it means, function `fun` which takes `x1` of type `τ1` as an argument can be **reduced** to the same function.

May be [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16201/double-down-facing-arrow-in-operational-semantics) on SE might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really had problem finding anything on that symbol!